# Modal Viewcontoller covers uiTabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar Based app and when i present a modal view controller, it takes covers the uitabBar, please why is this?

View Before presenting contoller:

[image]

This is how i present the modal view controller from the home page:

```
SearchSongViewController *Search_MusicTableView = [[SearchSongViewController alloc] init];
    Search_MusicTableView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:Search_MusicTableView animated:YES];
```

View After presenting the modal view controller:

[image]

This viewcontroller covers the whole uitabbar, please how should i present the viewcontoller so that it doesn't cover the tabbar ?

Thanks a million !

Answer (score 2):

I think this is normal with modal view controllers so I would suggest you just to use a `push` segue.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to ios but segue Isn't that with storyboard ? plus the same thing still happens if i'm trying to presentviewcontroller so it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Yeah that's with storyboard sorry I don't know how to do it without storyboard because I'm quite new, too and I always use storyboard.